# Split UIWebView load and display in different threads

Tags: iphone, multithreading

Is it possible for UIWebView to load a local html page and then run javascript in one thread, and display the page in main thread ? Pseudocode like this:

```
bool refresh;
WebView* webView;
void main() {
    newThreadStarts();
    while(true) {
        if (refresh) {
            webView->Refresh();
        }
        // a lot of other time-consuming code go here
        sleep(1000);
    }
}

void newThreadLoop() {
    webView->Load();
    while(true) {
        evaluateJavaScript();
        sleep(1000);
    }
}
```

ps: i'm a newbie on cocoa and iPhone development.

Answer (score 0):

Nope :(

The way a UIWebView can execute javascript - UIWebView stringByEvaluatingJavascriptFromString: - must be run on the main thread, or else your app will very quickly crash.

There's a similar question here: [Can I run a UIWebView in a seperate thread?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11139509/can-i-run-a-uiwebview-in-a-seperate-thread)